# period matrix of the complex torus

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

I'm reading about **Complex Torus** (H. Lange and C. Birkenhake, Complex Abelian Varieties - Chapter 1).

**In the book it is written:**

"In order to describe a complex totus $X=V/\Lambda$, choose bases $e_{1},...,e_{g}$ of $V$ and $\lambda_{1},...,\lambda_{2g}$ of the lattice $\Lambda$"

The author walks to set the **period matrix** for $X=V/\Lambda$.

I'm confused about the cardinality of generators of the lattice. Why $2g$ ??

I understand that for example:

Take $n$ vectors $v_{1},...,v_{g} \in \mathbb{C}^{g}$ that are linearly

independent over $\mathbb{C}$. Then the lattice $\Lambda$ generated by these vectors consists of all linear combinations

$a_{1}v_{1}+...+a_{g}v_{g}$, where $a_{1},...,a_{g} \in \mathbb{Z}$.

And here is my question: How can I say that the cardinality of generator set of lattice is $2g$?

Comment: A lattice is the abelian group generated by a **real** basis of the real vector space underlying $\mathbb C^n$ and such a basis has  $2n$ elements.

Comment: So as the question ... for $n$ vectors $v_{1},...,v_{g} \in \mathbb{C}^{g}$ that are linearly independent the generators of the lattice are $(Re(v_{1}),Im(v_{1}),...,Re(v_{g}),Im(v_{g}))$. And therefore,  the cardinality of generator set of lattice is 2g. It is?

Comment: No, not necessarily. For example  $1$ is a complex basis basis of $\mathbb C$, but $1,0$ is not a real basis. You have to take a real basis and not start with a complex basis.